# CMake Windows Command Path Elegant Solution

Tags: cmake

I'm using an external library without CMake and building this library is a little tedious so I decided to use external scripts for that purpose:

- one for configuration which runs the projects own build system, and
- one for the actual build which simply runs MSBuild on the generated VS solution.

I want to copy the script to the directory where the archive is unpacked to, and execute it afterwards.

**Current CMake File**

```
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/scripts/configure_OpenDDS_template.bat CONFIGURE_SCRIPT)
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/scripts/build_OpenDDS_template.bat BUILD_SCRIPT)

ExternalProject_Add(OpenDDS
  PREFIX OpenDDS
  URL ${CLD}/OpenDDS-DDS-3.12.1.zip
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmd /C "cd ../OpenDDS && copy ${CONFIGURE_SCRIPT} configure_OpenDDS.bat && call configure_OpenDDS.bat"
  BUILD_COMMAND copy ${BUILD_SCRIPT} ${BUILD_COPY}
  INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```

My question is whether there is a better or shorter or more elegant solution to have the absolute paths used in `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` and `BUILD_COMMAND` in correct Windows form than to use the conversion function from *file*. My current solution is acceptable for small projects in my opinion but you really want CMake to handle the path conversion for you without the excessive use of additional variables. I mean, CMake already handles the OS specific configuration of absolute paths for normal use but not within functions that execute pure OS commands like `execute_process`.

Comment: I don't know of a silver bullet, and I've been doing exactly the same. As for your concern when it comes to bigger projects, you can isolate those steps in a function and reuse it (assuming that your standard convention would be to have a `configure` and a `build` script for each and accommodate for unexpected stuff with [optional arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html)) per external project.

Comment: @compor Hmm, this is unfortunate but answers my question :-)